# HelperText attibute does not support complex content (mixed C# and markup)

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I just want my component to have some HelperText saying `Please provide a valid @outlook.com email`. But it's picking up on the `@` symbol and causing errors. How can I tell it to process it as a character in the string?

```
<MudTextField @bind-Text="Email" T="string" MaxLength="250" 
  Class="mt-2" Label="E-Mail*" 
  HelperText="Please provide a valid @outlook.com email" 
  HelperTextOnFocus="true" Margin="Margin.Dense" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
```

Comment: Tip: always include full and literal error messages. Helps others find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least three options that I can think of off the top of my head.

**1. Use an expression containing the literal string**

`HelperText="@("Please provide a valid @outlook.com email")"`

**2. Bind to a local property**

```
<MudTextField 
  HelperText="@EmailHelperText"  />

@code {
  private string EmailHelperText { get; } 
    = "Please provide a valid @outlook.com email";
}
```

**3. Replace the `@` with the HTML entity `&#64;`**

`HelperText="Please provide a valid &#64;outlook.com email"`

Demo: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQSYvuTnXcvoquF

(Press the green play icon in the top left of the demo to view)